# How to add unique information to a row in a gridview using winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, datagridview

I am working on designing a small POS system using C# and Winforms. I am using grid view to add scanned item to a transaction (items being sold.) I am looking to collect some tracking information for some items depending of item type.

For example, if a customer is buying a speaker, head phone and a new cell phone. I would need to obtain additional tracking information for the cell phone. I need to know

1. If the phone was sold as "New Activation" or "Phone Upgrade"
2. Phone number for that phone
3. A serial number
4. The new phone carrier
5. The carrier's Plan that was selected.

Each item in the database have a type. I could display another form when item if a certain type is added to the transaction (just before it is added.) and then the user will be promoted to fill before the item is actually added to the transaction.

I am struggling with how to add the additional information to the transaction. I could add hidden column with that additional information to the gridview (one column for, phone number, carrier, plan, serial. But there could be so many different hidden column, and I am not sure if the is my only option?

Answer (score 0):

For the back-end, there are three approaches (possibly more) that could be used.

The first approach is to have your database table have 20 additional columns, e.g. CustomName1, CustomValue1, CustomName2, CustomValue2, etc. I've seen this approach used in a couple systems, personally I don't like it because it's limited in the number of fields and it's hard to query.

The second approach is to generalize the first approach into a separate table. E.g. The columns will be POSID, FieldName, FieldValue.

The third approach is to have predefined tables for each particular type of sold product.

The UI design is a separate issue. A simple approach is to provide a "More..." button that is only enabled when a single item in the DGV is selected. When clicked, it will open a form that contains additional input fields.

Another approach is that when the type of product is selected, the additional columns are added to the DGV.

Comment: Thank you.  I am sorry for not being clear in my question. I am not worried about a the database part of it and how to store it. I am trying to figure out a way to capture the info. Like if I am selling 2 phones in the same transaction, how would I save the information for the 2 phones separately so when I am ready to insert the records to the database I would look for that additional data

Comment: Typically you will have a business object that stores all the data. So you have a POSData object for each sale. Inside that object you will store the additional data. When the sale is complete, you process each POSData and insert the data to the appropriate tables.